How get task attributes from extra link plugin?
I am trying to implement custom extralink so I have get_link function:
class KubernetesPodLogsLink(BaseOperatorLink):
    name = "Pod logs"
    operators = [MyKubeOperator]

    def get_link(self, operator: BaseOperator, *, ti_key: TaskInstanceKey):

        return "https://google.com"

Here I need to access task instance attributes, but TaskInstanceKey only what I have. It contains only ids about DAG,
task, run. How get current TaskInstance execution from TaskInstanceKey?
